# Does Ruby have a string.startswith("abc") built in method?

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby have a `some_string.starts_with("abc")` method that's built in?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130364/ruby-doesnt-have-a-string-startswithabc-built-in-method

Comment: Incidentally, are you asking about Ruby, or about Rails?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

It's called [`String#start_with?`](http://RubyDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/String#start_with%3F-instance_method), not `String#startswith`: In Ruby, the names of boolean-ish methods end with `?` and the words in method names are separated with an `_`. On Rails you can use the alias [`String#starts_with?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/StartsEndsWith/starts_with%3F) (note the plural - and note that this method is deprecated).  Personally, I'd prefer `String#starts_with?` over the actual `String#start_with?`

Comment: Matz has said he prefers without the s as it then looks like second person singular or third person plural.

Comment: String#start_with? was introduced in ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.0 - for older versions you may want to use one of the regex or index versions mentioned in other answers.

Comment: in Rails, you can use String#starts_with?

Comment: @Abdo do you know what gem adds that method? I would like to use it in my off rails programs too.

Comment: @anthropomorphic https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with.rb ; it's an alias for String#start_with?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The only problem being that "a string" is third person singular! (Ergo, 's' should not have been dropped).

Comment: @user456584 you're thinking in English, not Japanese.

Comment: some_string.start_with?("abc")

Comment: Matz' approach makes sense if you think of the Ruby paradigm as inspired by Smalltalk. Methods calls are essentially "sending a message". In this case, asking the String "do you start with <foo>?"

Comment: I clarified the answer to be correct for ruby while still maintaining the authors preference for the plural, rails solution.  (After finding this answer myself and trying to use 'starts_with?' on ruby :) )

Answer (score 46):

Your question title and your question body are different. *Ruby* does not have a starts_with? method. *Rails*, which is a Ruby *framework*, however, *does*, as sepp2k states. See his comment on his answer for the link to the documentation for it.

You could always use a regular expression though:

```
if SomeString.match(/^abc/) 
   # SomeString starts with abc
```

`^` means "start of string" in regular expressions

Comment: I took the subject+bods combination to mean "Ruby doesn't have a starts_with method. Does rails?".

Comment: @sepp2k, but it is `?` in question title )

Comment: String has start_with? since ruby 1.9 ( http://eigenclass.org/hiki/Changes+in+Ruby+1.9#l124 )

Comment: @steenslag - ruby 1.8.7 also has start_with? - [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.8.7/String#start_with%3F-instance_method) and [1.8.7 release notes](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_8_7/NEWS)

Comment: careful when building regexes out of string literals - remember to escape any special chars. there is a function for that fi the strings literals can be unpredictable

Comment: Generally, '\A` is preferable over '^' in Ruby regexps.

Comment: Also `.match?` is recommended now if you don't need the result.

Answer (score 20):

If this is for a non-Rails project, I'd use `String#index`:

```
"foobar".index("foo") == 0  # => true
```

Comment: This would, however, be more performance-intensive, in that a `start_with?` method can simply confirm that the beginning of the string matches the given string—thus processing at most *n* characters where *n* is the length of the given string—whereas `index` will have to search the entire base string. In a failure case, `starts_with?` will take one access (per string) and comparison, whereas `index` will walk almost the full length of the base string.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `String =~ Regex`. It returns position of full regex match in string.

```
irb> ("abc" =~ %r"abc") == 0
=> true
irb> ("aabc" =~ %r"abc") == 0
=> false
```

Comment: Please use `//` instead of `%r` whenever possible.