# Searching for a string using user input

Tags: ruby

My goal is to have the user enter a string to find a string in an array. Im using strings include? function to search but its returning the wrong data.

```
 puts "Enter Artist(all or partial name):"   
 search_artist = gets.chomp
 list.each do |x|
     if x.artist.include? (search_artist)
       num += 1
       x.to_s
     else
       puts "none found"
     end   end
```

search_artist = 'a' (because im looking for AARON...)

returns:

```
AARON KDL NOT VALID 2
ZAC CHICKEN ROCK 1289
2 records found
```

should be:

```
AARON KDL NOT VALID 2     
1 record found`
```

The problem is that both strings include 'a' somewhere in the string. 
How do I search from the beginning of the string?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4130364/1531971

Comment: The indentation here is extremely chaotic and it's making the code hard to follow. Remember to clean up your code, especially when asking on Stack Overflow. It helps us establish intent.

Comment: Try changing `include?` to [String#start_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Ruby have a string.startswith("abc") built in method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130364/does-ruby-have-a-string-startswithabc-built-in-method)

Answer (score 3):

There's a really easy way of doing this with [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
matches = list.grep(search_artist)

if (matches.empty?)
  puts "none found"
end
```

To count the number of matches you can just `matches.length`.

If you want a *case insensitive* match, then you want this:

```
matches = list.grep(Regexp.new(search_artist, Regexp::IGNORECASE))
```

Where that flag creates a case-insensitive regular expression to match more broadly.

**Edit**: To anchor this search to the beginning of the string:

```
matches = list.grep(Regexp.new('\A' + Regexp.escape(search_artist), Regexp::IGNORECASE))
```

Where `\A` anchors to the beginning of the string.

Comment: @moveson As Carey pointed out, the request was actually for "search from the beginning of the string" so it needs the `\A` anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Other option, just if the search is limited to the first letter, case insensitive:

```
found = list.select { |x| [search_artist.downcase, search_artist.upcase].include? x[0] }
found.each { |e| puts e }
puts "Found #{found.size} records"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Regular expressions:

```
puts "Enter Artist(all or partial name):"   
search_artist = gets.chomp

puts list.select do |x|
  x.artist.start_with?(search_artist)
end
```